# Xmpp chat room not created version smack-android:4.1.6

Tags: android

```
 MultiUserChat chatRoom = new MultiUserChat(connection, "room786@conference.dishaserver");
    try {
        chatRoom.create("nagarjuna");
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Form form = null;
    List owners = new ArrayList();
    owners.add("Migankit@"+"cricketmatchs.com");
    try {
        form = chatRoom.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "room786");
    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners",owners);
    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
    try {
        chatRoom.sendConfigurationForm(form);
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I added `MultiUserChat` class I got the following error: `MultiUserChat is not public, cannot be accessed from outside package`. Please help me with where I am wrong.

Comment: the class isn't available from outside the package. Not familar with the library, but if this is a class you made it has to be public. If it is a library class, you can't use it as it can't be accessed from outside the package

Comment: ok thanks for your reply so please suggest me how to use MultiUserChat class, i need to add library for this.

Comment: I have suggested how you use it. I don't know the library, but it isn't accessible from outside the package. If you don't know what that means, you really need to learn Java before you continue making the app